# "NoAlertPresentException:mesage: No such alert" when using selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium

I tried everything I can find online, still can't solve this issue.
I am using selenium to login a site. There is a javascript login popup windows that requires username and password.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qp6Df.jpg)
Below is the code which doesn't work.

```
driver.get(url)
sleep(5)
alert=driver.switch_to.alert
```

I also tried use `request.get(https://username:password@site)`, it works, but I can't get the content after login. I assume it is javascript page.
Anyone can help me with this issue. I would really appreciate. I have worked on this issue for whole day long.

Answer (score -1):

This is not an alert, rather an example of a page with basic authentication. If you are using Selenium4, then here is an article by Simon Stewart about how you can handle this - [link](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2021/a-tour-of-4-authentication/)

Also, you can see this blog post which takes a slightly different approach to same problem, using Selenium 4 and Chrome Devtools - [link](https://medium.com/automationmaster/handling-basic-authentication-window-with-selenium-webdriver-and-devtools-api-ec716965fdb6)